# Custom Tabs keeps opening web browser

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I am trying to load  a web url by using Custom Tabs.

I am using following version of `custom tabs`

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
```

The issue is that it keeps opening chrome web browser instead of custom tabs type layout descibed in the below picture.

[image: Custom Tabs Example]

This is my code.

```
    public void createCustomTab(String url){


        // CustomTabsIntent.Builder used to configure CustomTabsIntent.
                CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

        // CustomTabsIntent used to launch the URL
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();

        // Open the Custom Tab
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(eContext, Uri.parse(url));

}
```

I am trying this on a `Lollipop device`, and my current target SDK is `27`

Comment: Is your Chrome up-to-date?

Comment: Just checked `Google Chrome: Fast & secure app` on play store, its not showing any update button on my device.